# Are greatly more resources devoted to investigating the circumstances around missing women and girls than to those around missing boys and men?

Tags: united-kingdom, gender

We have seen two recent national media spectacles around the missing persons cases of Nicola Bulley and Gaynor Lord, and these have followed the admittedly gruesome national spectacle around the disappearance of Sarah Everard. My personal hunch was that Everard's case received so much national and police attention because she was young and attractive, while Bulley's and Lord's have done in no small part because of the reflexive distrust of police that ensued from hers, while the police naturally want to preempt such distrust by showing that they are not complicit, nor corrupt or lazy in getting to the truth and bottom of what happened to them, even when it seems now most plausible with Lord that she simply committed some kind of mystical or contemplative suicide.

I remember seeing an opinionated media/political analysis column that was quite biting but which I unfortunately have not since been able to find again which presented several counter examples of women that had gone missing for weeks and then turned out to be raped and murdered, but nobody had ever heard of any of them. I don't remember if the column's thesis was that it was because they weren't middle class and white and attractive, or (actually I think it was more likely along the following latter lines) that it didn't suit some nefarious political agendas of distraction from other issues to blow the entire national media up with appeals for information about them due to the timing. I can't remember the details of this latter category of theories, but I think it might have been along the lines of the coinciding circumstances of the covid pandemic situation and a particular governmental need to distract the populace from what had at that time been coming out. In any event, the question raised by the author of why the discrepancy between the attention given to Everard and that not given to any of the others that none of us have even heard of was indisputably established. And the theory given by the author to answer it was, whatever it was, to my mind compellingly well supported.

Nonetheless, there is the to some degree analytical question of why this seems to case (that these 2 or 3 cases are receiving inordinate public and police attention), but it follows the purely empirical question as to whether they are in fact receiving such inordinate attention, whether in comparison with other missing female cases, or in comparison with any missing male cases. Do they?

Comment: Please note that the examples you mention are single cases while you ask for statistically significant differences in averages. That would require a very thorough study including a large number of cases. The given examples might just be outliers and not representative of typical missing person cases. Often media attention is self-enforcing, for example some outlets presenting news because it's in the news of other such outlets.

Comment: It is possible: [Missing white woman syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Missing_white_woman_syndrome)

Comment: Anecdotal evidence can still be useful, for example if even a single counter example of a male missing person receiving so much painstaking effort then there is a question to be answered.

Comment: FWIW, in the U.S. "Out of those 20 and under who were reported missing, 54 percent were female, while that number was 39 percent for those over the age of 21." https://www.statista.com/chart/30487/missing-persons-age-race-sex/#:~:text=Out%20of%20those%2020%20and,still%20be%20in%20great%20danger.

Comment: Ok, well that is interesting but it would also seem to me orthogonal to the question of how much attention and  other resources are subsequently devoted to resolving those reports.